# How to find the top 5 Relationship and their Time stamp values over a week data using cypher query

Tags: neo4j

In my GraphDatabase I have following data.

1)Senders as Nodes
2)Receivers as Nodes
3)Keywords as relationship between sender and receiver
4)Timestamp as relationship property.

I need to extract top 5 keywords , their count and corresponding timestamp value over a week using cypher query.
(Simply I want to maintain a timeline((time stamp is in format of :Tue Mar 05 12:40:36 ) for my top 5 keywords in last 7 days)

Can someone please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance

Gouse.

Comment: You'll probably want to convert your dates to a Long timestamp. Then use something like this in your Cypher statement:
    WHERE rel.timestamp > 54341564654
where the number represents the timestamp of 7 days ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start n=node(*)
match n-[r:]-m
where has(r.timestamp) and r.timestamp>({now-(60*60*24*7)}) //60 second, 60 minutes, 24 hours, 7 days = 7 days timestamp period;
with r, count(*) as cnt
return type(r), cnt order by cnt desc limit 5
```

keep the time format as a long timestamp as tstorms suggested